# Webhook triggered when a user delete a conversation with your page

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, messenger

I want to know if Facebook can call a webhook when a user delete a conversation with your page in messenger ?

I try to find this information in the [webhooks references](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference)... 1 hour searching and can't find anything about that.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: You’d have to check whether subscribing to the conversations field covers that as well ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't understand, it's webhook related ? Or another way to find this information ?

Comment: You can subscribe to changes to the conversations field, about which the documentation simply says, “Describes changes in conversation threads involving a page.” - so whether a user deleting a conversation is covered by that, is not explicitly mentioned ... therefor, _test it_ if you need to know.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try.